# Display a formatted text / message on p:confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

When a row in [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml) is right-clicked, [`<p:contextMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/contextmenu/basic.xhtml) appears with a delete option. When this option is clicked, [`<p:confirmDialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml) appears with two buttons `Yes` and `No` - a conformation warning about deleting the current row as follows.

```
<p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
    <p:menuitem oncomplete="confirmDelete.show()"
                value="Delete"
                update="confirmDialog"
                process="@this dataTable"
                actionListener="#{testManagedBean.deleteActionListener}"
                icon="ui-icon-close" ajax="true"/>
</p:contextMenu>

<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
                 widgetVar="confirmDelete"

                 message="#{testManagedBean.message}"

                 header="Message"
                 severity="alert"
                 closeOnEscape="true"
                 showEffect="slide"
                 hideEffect="fold"
                 appendTo="@(body)"
                 closable="true">

    <p:commandButton id="btnYes"
                     value="Yes"
                     process="@this"
                     oncomplete="confirmDelete.hide()"
                     actionListener="#{testManagedBean.deleteActionListener}" 
                     update="dataTable"/>

    <p:commandButton id="btnNo"
                     value="No"
                     onclick="confirmDelete.hide()"
                     type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Is there a way to set the `message` attribute with a formatted message on this dialog.

For example, the property `testManagedBean.message` in its managed bean is set to a string like

`You are about to delete <font color='#ff0000'>2</font> rows. <br/>This action will never be undone. <br/>Are you sure?`

The confirm dialog displays this string as a whole. HTML in this string should be interpreted as HTML. I don't see any attribute like `escape` in `<p:confirmDialog>`.

Is there a way to display this string as a formatted message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an <s>ugly</s> solution nesting of `<f:facet name="message">` within `<p:confirmDialog>`.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
                 widgetVar="confirmDelete"

                 header="Message"
                 severity="alert"
                 closeOnEscape="true"
                 showEffect="slide"
                 hideEffect="fold"
                 appendTo="@(body)"
                 closable="true">

    <p:commandButton id="btnYes"
                     value="Yes"
                     process="@this"
                     oncomplete="confirmDelete.hide()"
                     actionListener="#{testManagedBean.deleteActionListener}"
                     update="dataTable"/>

    <p:commandButton id="btnNo"
                     value="No"
                     onclick="confirmDelete.hide()"
                     type="button" />

    <f:facet name="message">
        <h:outputFormat value="#{testManagedBean.message}" escape="false"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Removing the `message` attribute from `<p:comfirmDialog>` and nesting `<f:facet name="message">` inside it.

Note : `<h:outputFormat>` is only needed, if one or more parameters need to be passed by means of nested `<f:param>` to be substituted in respective placeholders (`{0}`) in the message text. Just keep on using `<h:outputText escape="false">`, if no such parameters need to be passed.

Comment: Why is this solution 'ugly'?

Comment: `<f:facet name="message">` is not guaranteed to work on every JSF version unless it is a decent JSF version.