# HTML tags and newline do not work with p:confirmDialog

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use html tags or new line with `<p:confirmDialog>` message.

**Xhtml** is

```
<h:form>
  <p:commandButton value="Open Confirm Dialog" actionListener="#{bean.getConfirmDlgMsg}" update="confirmDlgId" oncomplete="confrimDlg.show();"/>
</h:form>

<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDlgId" widgetVar="confrimDlg" header="Test Header"
message="#{bean.msg}">
   <p:commandButton value="Yes"/>
   <p:commandButton value="No"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

**Bean** is

```
private String msg;
//getter and setter for msg
public void getConfirmDlgMsg()
{
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Hi");
  sb.append("\n");
  sb.append("<b>Welcome</b>");
  setMsg(sb.toString());
}
```

The confirmDialog message must be like

Hi
**Welcome**

But I get 
Hi `<b>` Welcome `</b>`

As `\n` did not work, I tried `<br/>`. But these tags were getting printed.

Then I tried `sb.append(String.format("<strong> %s <strong>")","Welcome");`
But the `<strong>` is getting printed.

Then used `<font><font>`

I tried using `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`. But there was no change.

Then I change the confirmDialog to

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDlgId" widgetVar="confrimDlg" header="Test Header">
   <f:facet name="message">
     <h:outputFormat value="#{bean.msg}" escape="false"/>
   </f:facet>
   <p:commandButton value="Yes"/>
   <p:commandButton value="No"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Here the tags does not get printed, but the required part of message does not get bold.

I had successfully used /n and `<br/>` with `StringBuilder` before.

I would like to know whether HTML tags or newline do not work with `<p:confirmDialog>`.
Any also, is there any way to use html tags with `<p:confirDialog>`?

I use primefaces 4 and jsf 2.2.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883132/display-a-formatted-text-message-on-primefaces-confirm-dialog Maybe this helps you.

Comment: I have tried that solution but still the tags get printed.

Comment: newline in html is <br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution by using css

**Xhtml** is

```
#confirmDlgId span.makeBold
{
    font-weight:bold;
}

<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDlgId" widgetVar="confrimDlg" header="Test Header">
   <f:facet name="message">
     <h:outputFormat value="#{bean.msg}" escape="false"/>
   </f:facet>
   <p:commandButton value="Yes"/>
   <p:commandButton value="No"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

**Bean is**

```
private String msg;
//getter and setter for msg
public void getConfirmDlgMsg()
{
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Hi");
  sb.append("\n");
  sb.append("<span class="makeBold">Welcome</span>");
  setMsg(sb.toString());
}
```